# Setting a cookie on an external domain through an image, doesn't seem to work

Tags: cookies, single-sign-on, session-cookies

I have `mysite.com` and `mysite.nl`.

I want to build single sign-on, someone signing in on .com should be signed in in .nl.

I do this by putting an image (1 pixel transparent PNG image) on the .nl domain which sends back a cookie in the response.

In my firefox dev tools, I see 'response cookie' and it's set. It looks like this:

[image]

I have made sure the domain is set to `mysite.nl`

But somehow, when I then navigate to `mysite.nl` I don't see the cookie set. Am I missing something? I tried disabling tracker blocking, but to no avail.

Google is doing it this way as well right? Ie., log in in Google and you're logged in in Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser makes a request to `xyz.mysite.com`, it has to drop the domain cookie for `mysite.nl`. This is due to the browser security model. If you want to achieve Single Sign On between `xyz.mysite.com` and `xyz.mysite.nl` you need some technology to 'transfer' the session token between the two domains. Either you use a standards-backed technology like SAML or OIDC or you use a proprietary mechanism. If you carefully look at the HTTP response, you will see two `Set-Cookie` HTTP response headers, one has `domain` property set to `mysite.com`, one has set `domain` property to `mysite.nl`.